# svn revision size in bytes

Tags: svn

Is there a way to tell how big a SVN revision is?

I don't mean in a hook, but after the fact (e.g. with svnlook?). I need the (rough) size in bytes, including any binary files that may have been added/changed.

Comment: Do you probably - meanwhile - know more/better options to get it done?

Comment: @wolf see https://stackoverflow.com/a/62008475/761095

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you mean "By how much did it increase the size of my repository?", and you have access to the server, and you are using FSFS, and you haven't packed your repository, then there is a way:

Let's assume you're looking for the "size" of revision 12345. Inside your repository's directory you'll find the subdirectory `db`. Here's a picture:

```
    repository/
        db/
            revs/
                12/
                    12345   <----+
            revprops/            | add together the sizes of these two
                12/              | files.
                    12345   <----+
```

Comment: With packed format and manifest files this becomes nowadays trickier. IMHO there should be support from svnlook or alike for this!

Comment: @jdehaan use `svnadmin rev-size`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/62008475/761095

Answer (score 2):

Starting [with Subversion 1.13](https://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.13) you can use the `svnadmin rev-size` command to find out the size of a revision. This command works both for packed and unpacked revisions.

> - New 'svnadmin rev-size' command to report revision size (r1857624)

Here is an example:

```
C:\Repositories>svnadmin rev-size MyRepo2 -r 1234
        4616 bytes in revision 1234
```

Here is a built-in help:

```
rev-size: usage: svnadmin rev-size REPOS_PATH -r REVISION

Print the total size in bytes of the representation on disk of
revision REVISION.

The size includes revision properties and excludes FSFS indexes.

Valid options:
  -r [--revision] ARG      : specify revision number ARG (or X:Y range)
  -q [--quiet]             : print only the size and a newline
  -M [--memory-cache-size] ARG : size of the extra in-memory cache in MB used to
                             minimize redundant operations. Default: 16.
                             [used for FSFS repositories only]

(Use '-v' to show global and experimental options.)
```

Comment: I wish this would have been available earlier :-). Thanks for the hint!